# UISearchController broken animation when focused

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, ios12

I've found a problem in the UISearchController animation when it's tapped, and I managed to replicate in a simple project that I'll attach.

Basically when I tap the UISearchController, the content bellow it snaps to the top of the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide before the animation finishes. Which causes a not so smooth animation.

You can see the occurrence in this small video:
https://streamable.com/y1tzn

The only thing I do in my ViewController is:

```
private lazy var text: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "dfgh"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    setupSearchController()
    setupLabel()
}

 func setupSearchController() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for names and emails"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
 }

func setupLabel() {
    view.addSubview(text)
    text.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    text.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

And on SceneDelegate:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let vc = ViewController()
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    window?.rootViewController = nc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

[TestProject](https://github.com/carlosdamiao/TestSearch)

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thanks everyone

EDIT: Added Git Repo

Comment: +1 for a good question.
Please, could you post the code on Github? The link you shared has restricted access rights.

Comment: If you don't like the way `UISearchController` works, use `UISearchBar` instead.

Comment: Sorry. Here you go:
https://github.com/carlosdamiao/TestSearch

Comment: @ElTomato, on my project we have a Large Title. When adding a UISearchBar as a navigation item, it gets put above the title of the navigationbar.

Comment: You don't have to use the search bar with the navigation controller.

Comment: In my project I've a tableView instead of a UILabel, and when we scroll there is an animation with the title going from large title to small title. I want to preserve that.
If we put the searchbar in between the title and the tableview we loose that animation, because the whole viewcontroller doesn't scroll, only the searchbar.
And if we put it inside the tableview, we can't make it always visible...